# How to invoke SignalR hub operations from the server

Tags: signalr

The [SignalR wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs) covers how to broadcast over a hub from outside of a hub. However, this calls the client side operation:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
context.Clients.Group(group).addMessage(message);
```

Is there a way to invoke the **Hub Operation**, ideally in a strongly typed way? e.g.

```
GetHubContext<MyHub>().Invoke(h => h.Say(message))
```

I know this is possible by connecting to the hub using the .NET client but this seems wrong for when the calling code is on the same server as the hub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. That's like trying to invoke an MVC controller from the server side (you just don't do it). Just move the common logic into a shared helper and call that helper from both the hub and your other server side code.

Comment: Except only the Hub has the ability to broadcast to clients so how would a helper, help? The current method requires the class to know the client side operations, something I would prefer to be encapsulated in the hub.

Comment: Hub methods represent calls from client to server. When you're in the body of a hub method you have access to things (like the http request and Caller's connection id and access to the Caller object and other things) that don't make sense from the server to server (Using the MVC controller analogy I thought would clear things up but I was wrong).

To your other point, clearly you didn't read the documenation. Scroll to the bottom https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs, but thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I read the docs but clearly had my abstractions mixed up. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @dfowler Do you think is a good option to implement the static methods within the Hub class itself? 
In the documentation example instead of "MemberManager" or "Notifier" having those methods directly in the Hub class.
The rationale behind doing so is basically avoid the usage of the dynamic properties outside of the Hub class.
Clear is that such methods will be dealing *only* with communication, no extra logic involved.

Answer (score 5):

Bit late to the party but, yes, there is.

The [stockticker sample nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Sample)  does this (although it doesn't entirely use it!):

Basically, you expose a static instance of the server side hub to make calls against.

In the sample the pattern is:

```
public class StockTicker
{
    // Singleton instance
    private readonly static Lazy<StockTicker> _instance = new Lazy<StockTicker>(
        () => new StockTicker(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StockTickerHub>().Clients));

...


    public static StockTicker Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }
```

...

This is then available to be called from anywhere and pretty much anywhen!:

```
StockTicker.Instance.OpenMarket();
```

The same example is also covered by a blog post at the [asp.net site](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look:
https://github.com/i-e-b/SignalR-TypeSafeClient

you can use this library.

Tiz